# spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-sftp Sftp Sink , file-expression is not working

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-integration-sftp

I am using stfp sink and trying to name the remote file based on header. I am providing following property to name the file on remote

sftp.file-expression=payload.headers['id'] + payload.headers['file_name']

I also tried
sftp.file-expression=headers['id'] + headers['file_name']

but these is not working and in remote the original filename is kept. Is this the right way to write SpEL expression. Also I don't get any error with this property except the prope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be `sftp.filename-expression`:

> sftp.filename-expression
>
> ```
>           A SpEL expression to generate the remote file name. (Expression, default: <none>)
> ```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Bacon.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-modules-sinks.html#_options_50

Comment: What an oversight, thanks for pointing it out, I am going to try this. Any suggestion of which is the correct way to get values from header , payload.headers['id'] or headers['id'].

Comment: The root object for evaluation context is `Message` which has `getPayload()` and `getHeaders()` methods. So, to reach headers you really should perform `headers` property accessor expression. If your `payload` has `getHeaders()` accessor, too, that won't be surprise to have `payload.headers['id']` as valid SpEL as well.